# How to resolve NPM audit vulnerabilities?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-scripts, npm-audit

After running NPM audit I have identified 5 critical issues. I have tried updating  `@storybook/addon-essentials` & `@storybook/react` in order to resolve 4 of these as they say `patched in >=x.x.x` which implies to me they have been resolved in the atleast the latest versions.

I ran `npm i @storybook/addon-essentials@latest @storybook/react@latest` and can see package.json (and lock) have latest versions but running an audit again shows the same critical vulnerabilities.

Is there something else I need to update in order to resolve these or have I done something wrong when updating to latest?

*There are also some moderate and high vulnerabilities but I have grepped just the critical in order to focus on them for now*

*I should also add we are using a private registery for our npm installs but it doesn't support audit so having to run `npm audit --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org` against NPM registry. Not sure if this will make a difference.*

[image]

Comment: Pay attention to the Path section. You use `@storybook/react` which depends on `@storybook/core` which depends on a chain of things all the way down to `immer` which has a vulnerability. The entire chain needs an update released to pull in the newer version.

Comment: But isn't `@storybook/core` a dependency of `@storybook/react`? Meaning if I update `@storybook/react` it should update it's dependencies (assuming they have been updated in their latest versions)

Comment: "assuming they have been updated in their latest versions" is the operative part there.

Comment: Yes but in the screenshot of the audit output in my original post, it shows "patched in >=x.x.x". Does that not imply it has been fixed in the latest version?

Comment: The latest version of immer. Doesn't mean that react-dev-tools has been patched to depend on that version of immer. Or, if it has, that @storybook/builder-webpack4 has been patched to depend on that version of react-dev-tools. etc.

Comment: In this case, while `react-dev-utils`'s [package.json](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-dev-utils/package.json) has been updated at some point, since then, no new package has been released. Not sure how bad that is, as it seems this package is only installed as a devDependency—you might not even have it on-disk (try `npm ls --all`).

Comment: I have the same problem now. Did you managed to find any solution for this? @Stretch0

Comment: I have not yet been able to resolve this yet but one thought I had was perhaps using [npm overrides](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) to force the package that has a bad dependency to use a newer version. Not sure if this will work or not, might depend on if there are breaking changes?

Answer (score -1):

Try running `npm audit fix` ([Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-audit#examples))

Comment: I should have added that I had tried this. This resolves some of the moderate ones but still shows 5 critical

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was downvoted - it's a valid answer!
It's worth noting that some vulnerabilities are more "valid" than others too - you can run `npm audit --production` to review packages used in production code only - i.e. packaged imported directly in your code.